# Importing JSON file into Firebase error

Tags: json, firebase

I keep getting that there is an error uploading/importing my JSON file into Firebase. I initially had an excel spreadsheet that I saved as a CSV file, then I used a CSV to JSON converter.

I validated the JSON file (which have the .json extension) with a couple of online tools.

Though, I'm still getting an error.

Here is an example of my JSON:

```json
{
    "Rk": 1,
    "Tm": "SEA",
    "H/A": "H",
    "DOW": "Sun",
    "Opp": "CLE",
    "QB": "Russell Wilson",
    "Grade": "BLUE",
    "Def mu pts": 4,
    "Inj status": 0,
    "Notes": "Got to wonder if not having a proven power RB under center will negatively impact Wilson's production.",
    "TFS $50K": "$8,300",
    "Init sal": "$8,300",
    "Var": "$0",
    "WC": 0
}
```

Comment: Please add the error you're getting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is your key's..

Firebase keys must be:

> UTF-8 encoded, cannot contain . $ # [ ] / or ASCII control characters
>   0-31 or 127

your $50k key and the H/A are the issues.

Comment: That was it. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Glad that helped. Please accept the answer if it was correct. :-)